# Is it possible to specify the alternative hypothesis in Mann-Whitney U tests in Scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

I'd like to calculate the one-sided p-value of x > y using the [scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html#scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu) function:

```
u_value, p_value = scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu(x, y)
```

however there is nowhere to specify the alternative hypothesis. In R it is possible by using:

`wilcox.test(x, y, alternative = 'greater')`.

Does anyone know if it is possible to do this in python using scipy or any other package?

Comment: I might be wrong, but this test seems to be the one you're looking for. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ranksums.html

Comment: Thanks! They are similar tests, hopefully in this implementation the z-score has the sign still in it so I can figure out the direction of change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Scipy 0.17.0, you can now do `scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu(x, y, alternative='greater')`.